# Web Services: Unexpected EOF in prolog - I get this when I use Apache CXF and a method that has a POJO parameter

Tags: apache, service, cxf

I have the following login service interface:

```java
@Path("/loginService/")
@WebService(serviceName = "LoginService", name = "LoginService", targetNamespace = "http://ws.test.com")
public interface LoginService {
    /**
     * Takes an authentication request, and returns an authentication response.
     * In the event of an authentication failure, an HTTP status of 401 should
     * be returned.
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    @WebMethod
    @GET
    @Path("/")  
    public AuthenticationResponse login(@WebParam(name = "request") final AuthenticationRequest request);
}
```

I have the following in my spring file

```xml
<bean id="loginService" autowire="autodetect"
    class="com.test.mobile.webservices.authentication.LoginServiceImpl">
</bean>



<jaxws:endpoint id="LoginServiceEndpoint"
                serviceName="LoginService"
                implementorClass="com.test.mobile.webservices.authentication.LoginService"
                implementor="#loginService"
                address="/loginService">
    <jaxws:serviceFactory>
        <ref bean="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory"/>
    </jaxws:serviceFactory>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

When I attempt to hit the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/TPCMobileWS/api/rest/loginService?wsdl
```

I get the following message:

> JAXBException occurred : Unexpected EOF in prolog  at [row,col
>   {unknown-source}]: [1,0]. Unexpected EOF in prolog  at [row,col
>   {unknown-source}]: [1,0].

If I remove completely the "request" parameter in the login method, the URL hit above works just fine... no error, shows the right data.

What am I doing wrong when passing that POJO?  It just has a couple primitive types in it with getters and setters.   Am I missing some annotations?

Your help is MUCH appreciated!

Below is the Authentication Request:

```java
package com.test.mobile.webservices.authentication;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.test.mobile.webservices.Localization;

@XmlRootElement
public class AuthenticationRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;
    private Localization.Country country;
    private String password;

    public AuthenticationRequest() {

    }

    /**
     * For now, this is the consultant's ID.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * The country that the consultant is associated with, as a two letter ISO
     * country code.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Localization.Country getCountryCode() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(Localization.Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    /**
     * The consultant's password.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is to generate WSDL on the fly from the model. How have you generated `AuthenticationRequest`? Could you share this class with us (I am mainly interested in class declarations and annotations for it)?

Comment: I just edited the original content and place it above.

Comment: @MarkRicard: Why you haven't annotated the properties? Add `@XmlElement` either to fields or to getters in `AuthenticationRequest`.

Comment: Try removing the Localization.Country stuff from there and see if that works.  Kind of wondering if that type is compatible or not.